# How to check for a character in a string and replace that character before insert

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, this question involves one part of a complicated stored procedure which inserts new entities into several tables.

The part that I'm currently having difficulty with needs to work like so:

1. insert entity with original name
2. check if name of new entity contains any special characters listed in table A 'Characters'
3. if yes, than replace that character with a 'replacement character' from table A

EDIT: I've gotten this to partially work but still not finished. I'm still having a problem showing each combination of character replacements. Also in the case of a replacement character occurring more than once, such as the '.', the substitutions needs to happen independently of one another.

ex: #www.test&aol.com -> #wwwtest&aol.com, #www.test&aolcom

Here's a rough start, I know parts of this aren't going to work, but I thought it was a decent starting point:

```
declare @test varchar(50)
set @test = '#www.test&aol.com'
declare @len int, @ctr int
set @len = LEN(@test)
set @ctr = 1

declare @newName varchar(50)
declare @matchedChar table(match varchar(10),replaceChar varchar(10),processed int         default(0))
declare @alternateEntities table(name varchar(50))
declare @repChar varchar(10)
declare @selectedChar varchar(1)

while @ctr<=@len
begin
--Insert matching characters and replacement characters into table variable, 
--this is necessary for the # character, which has multiple replacement characters
insert into @matchedChar (match,replaceChar) select Character,ReplacementCharacter from     tblTransliterations where Character = SUBSTRING(@test,@ctr,1)

--loop 
while (select COUNT(*) from @matchedChar where processed = 0)>0
begin
    --get the top character from table variable
    set @selectedChar = (select top 1 match from @matchedChar where processed = 0)
    --get replacement character
    set @repChar = (select top 1 replaceChar from @matchedChar where processed = 0)
    --replace character in name string
    --set @newName = (select Replace(@test,@selectedChar,@repChar))     
    set @newName = (select STUFF(@test,CHARINDEX(@selectedChar,@test),1,@repChar))
    --update table variable to move onto next character
    update @matchedChar set processed = 1 where @repChar = replaceChar
    --add name with replaced character to alternate entities table
    insert into @alternateEntities (name) values (@newName)     
end
set @ctr = @ctr+1
set @len = LEN(@test)
end

select * from @alternateEntities
```

Comment: Could you provide some clarification on "in the case of a '#' character, there are multiple 'replacement character's (No, No., Number)"? Do you mean "#" needs to be replaced with "1", or "12", or "123", meaning a string of characters instead of a single character?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that as a literal example. So in the code I posted, the '#' symbol in the @test variable would need to be replaced with 'No', 'No.' and 'Number'

Comment: I thought you were trying to do it the other way round (switch No. OR No OR Number to #). If you're trying to switch # to all three of the other options, I don't know how you would do this without duplicating the record for each one.

I suppose in your other table you could have # switch to No, then No switch to No., then No. switch to Number. that would result in all records with a #, No or No. being switched to Number by the time the last pass was made. But I still don't understand why it needs to do all three.

Perhaps you can provide some more context?

Comment: does it mean, if '#' has replaces('@', '$', '^'), '#www.test&aol.com' would be '@$^www.test&aol.com'. or anything else !!!

Comment: The end goal is to have multiple entries inserted if any characters match what's listed in tblA. So for my example '#www.test&aol.com', there would be an insert using '#www.test&aol.com' as the name, and also inserts using 'No www.test&aol.com', 'No. www.test&aol.com' and 'Number www.test&aol.com'. To link them all the initial insert would have an ID value, which would link to a OID field the subsequent inserts would have. Does that make more sense?

Comment: one last qns. if we have # more than once, or more than one special char is used, than ?

Comment: In the case of more than one special char, there would have to be insertions corresponding to each possible character substitution and combination.

Comment: It would help to understand why you want to do this. Are you looking to create fuzzy searching possibilities?



If so, it might be better not to insert all the different combinations. If this is only part of your stored procedure, you are well on the way to creating a huge unmaintainable monster.


It's difficult to say without more details, but I'd go for a search function which checks the transliteration table, and searches for all combinations and substitutions, without having to persist them in tables.


Also if you can put some tables and test data up on sqlfiddle that would help no end.

Comment: Simon, I believe you're correct in saying this was heading towards being a real mess. With that in mind I've circled back and decided I can come to a cleaner solution by performing most of the desired tasks in my c# code instead of in sql. On a side note, I hadn't heard of sqlfiddle before so thanks for directing me to such a great site!

Comment: I think you'll be glad you made that decision! Stored procedures are usually ticking timebombs when it comes to maintainability in the future. But if you fancy putting yor project into sqlfiddle then I'm also up for suggesting an-sql based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping, use set-based approach.

1. Create a temp table and populate column 'Words' of type NVARCHAR(100), call the temp table Invalid_Words
2. Create a column on Invalid_Words for each token and make the col type = bit
3. Update the temp table bit columns if a word contains the token through a series of update statements

You now have defined which tokens were matched for each word.

The next part is to replace.